# How to change Failure text for two different possibilities?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have *ASP Login Control* in my page and a

```
<asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
```

What I want to do is that when I perform authentication in

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    DAL = new DataAccessLayer();
    conObj = DAL.openConnection();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE UEmail = '"+Login1.UserName+"'";

    SqlDataReader SQLDR = DAL.ExecuteQueryReturnValue(query);

    if (SQLDR.Read())
    {
        if (SQLDR["UPassword"].ToString() == Login1.Password.ToString())
        {

            Session["userName"] = SQLDR["UEmail"].ToString();
            e.Authenticated = true;
        }
        else {
            // Change the 'FailureText' to "password is incorrect"
            e.Authenticated = false;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        // Here I want to change the 'FailureText' to "User does not exists"
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }
   }
```

set the text of *FailureText* to

*"Incorrect Password"*

Or set to

*"User does not exist"*

for both possibilities.

Comment: Only you know the logic behind `Login1_Authenticate` share that part of the code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (SQLDR.HasRow())
{
    if(SQLDR.Read())
    {
        if (SQLDR["UEmail"].ToString() == Login1.UserName.ToString())
        {
            if (SQLDR["UPassword"].ToString() == Login1.Password.ToString())
            {
                Session["userName"] = SQLDR["UEmail"].ToString();
                e.Authenticated = true;
            }
            else
            {
                FailureText.Text = "password is incorrect";
                e.Authenticated = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    FailureText.Text = "User does not exists";
    e.Authenticated = false;
}
```

---

[HasRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the proper way to check if the table returns any row.

> **HasRows**
>   Gets a value that indicates whether the SqlDataReader
>   contains one or more rows. (Overrides DbDataReader.HasRows.)

You also needed to add one more check, to find out if the email matches but the password doesn't.

---

Is it a nested control, then add this before setting the text:

```
var FailureText = ((Literal)loginControl.FindControl("FailureText"));
```

or

```
var FailureText = loginControl.FindControl("FailureText") as Literal;
```

Comment: @meda - it's not LoginView. It's Login control.

Comment: @meda - I am not the OP, I just pointed the flaw in your assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a string variable within the method and set it accordingly:

```
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    DAL = new DataAccessLayer();
    conObj = DAL.openConnection();
    string query = "SELECT * FROM tblUser WHERE UEmail = '"+Login1.UserName+"'";
    string failureText=string.empty;

    SqlDataReader SQLDR = DAL.ExecuteQueryReturnValue(query);

    if (SQLDR.Read())
    {
        if (SQLDR["UPassword"].ToString() == Login1.Password.ToString())
        {

            Session["userName"] = SQLDR["UEmail"].ToString();
            e.Authenticated = true;
        }
        else {
            // Change the 'FailureText' to "password is incorrect"
            failureText="password is incorrect";
            e.Authenticated = false;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        // Here I want to change the 'FailureText' to "User does not exists"
        failureText="User does not exists";
        e.Authenticated = false;
    }

    if(!e.Authenticated)
    {
        // Use failureText where you need it
        FailureText.Text=string.Format("<h1>{0}</h1>", failureText);
    }
    else
    {
        FailureText.Text=string.empty;
    }
   }
```

**EDIT**: From further information that I got from you, I suspect you're trying to customize Login control. If so, just set `Login1.FailureText = failureText`.

Comment: The name 'FailureText' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Based on what you've provided, FailureText should be the ID of Literal control: <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>. If its not found, then it's either nested within another control or the page doesn't properly reference the codefile. Check those things.

Comment: It is nested in <asp:Login>'s <LayoutTemplate>
Is this the reason?

Comment: Still says same.

Yes it is nested in <LayoutTemplate>

Comment: @user3110335 - I'm guessing you're customizing the Login control? Otherwise there's no real reason why your login status message should be within Login control. If so, and you are customizing the login control then just set your login control's failure text: Login1.FailureText = failureText

Comment: I tried adding a custom asp:Label onto that built-in asp:Login but it shows the same error. 
Isn't that we cannot modify any Label that is on Asp:Login

Comment: @user3110335 - You confused me. Please read through this post to understand how to customize asp:Login control. http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/membership/membership.aspx